# Quickly insert source blocks in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

`org-mode` has the ability to render source code, with blocks of the following syntax:

```
#+NAME: <name>
#+BEGIN_SRC <language> <switches> <header arguments>
    <body>
#+END_SRC
```

Is there an existing command to quickly insert these blocks in `org-mode`, or do I need to use an external tool like `yasnippet`?

Comment: There are a couple of ways: (1) [Built-in Easy Templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html#Easy-Templates) (2) Using `hydra` package: [blogpost](http://oremacs.com/2015/03/07/hydra-org-templates/) (3) [Another snippet](http://paste.lisp.org/display/146101) for easy org source block insertion.

Comment: If you're pasting from Emacs, Emacs can fill in the major-mode and backlink for you: https://github.com/unhammer/org-rich-yank#org-rich-paste

Comment: 2021 update. The new way (org > 9.2) of inserting code blocks, with `C-c C-,` is detailed on [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40571/how-to-set-a-short-cut-for-begin-src-end-src/40587) post.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

As @kaushalmodi mentions in the comments you can use [`(org) Structure Templates`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html) to speed up insertion of different types of blocks.

The general procedure is to insert `<` followed by a *template selector* (usually a single letter) on an otherwise empty line and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

The template selector for a generic source block template is `s`, so typing `<s` followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> will give you this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC 

#+END_SRC
```

Point will be positioned at the end of the first line.

This is a good first approximation of what you want to achieve, but this is Emacs, so let's make it better!

You can define custom templates by adding one or more entries to a variable called `org-structure-template-alist`. For example:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("n" "#+NAME: ?"))
```

This code adds a `#+NAME:` template to `org-structure-template-alist`, using `n` as a template selector. After expanding this template point will be positioned at the location of `?`.

If you always name your code blocks, you can also overwrite the original version of the source block template with an extended version that includes the `#+NAME:` line:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
             '("s" "#+NAME: ?\n#+BEGIN_SRC \n\n#+END_SRC"))
```

Typing `<s` followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> will then give you:

```
#+NAME: 
#+BEGIN_SRC 

#+END_SRC
```

---

This is just the tip of the iceberg; you can use a similar approach to define additional templates for language-specific code blocks, code blocks with specific header arguments, etc.

Comment: Note: Easy Template is replaced with incompatible way in org-mode HEAD. I recommend to use yasnippet.

Comment: @lurdan is this still the case? I just tried `<s TAB` on Emacs 25 on Mac OS X and it seemed to work.

Comment: @RudolfOlah Yes, at least for org-mode (git) HEAD. Even with emacs26, bundled org-mode still has `org-try-structure-completion` function (for Easy-templates). But anyway, it will be replaced by Structure-templates in the future. cf. https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/c04e357f3d5d93484277a7e439847b1233b872bd

Comment: You now need `(require 'org-tempo)` to use `<s TAB`, but otherwise it works just as before.

Comment: `org-tempo` will still not allow you to define custom templates. They have a new API, and it's very limited.

Comment: Is it only me or do the begin and end strings are lower cased in the templates? Is there a variable to set to make them appear all uppercase?

Comment: Is it possible to change `<` to `,`? Is there a variable to set this?

Comment: Nowadays it's `C-c C-,` which runs `(org-insert-structure-template)`

Comment: @mgalgs why it does not work for me? emacs 27.1

Comment: It gives `Wrong type argument: stringp, ("#+NAME: ?` error

Comment: `<s TAB` does not work for me even if I have `(require 'org-tempo)`, tested on Emacs 27.2.

Answer (score 25):

> With just a few keystrokes, it is possible to insert empty structural
>   blocks, such as ‘#+BEGIN_SRC’ … ‘#+END_SRC’, or to wrap existing text
>   in such a block.
>
> C-c C-, (org-insert-structure-template)

[Documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates)

Comment: I used to use Easy Templates, but this way is quite better for me. Thanks.

Comment: C-c C-, means I hit c and then hit , with the Ctrl pressed? it does not work for me.

Comment: `C-,` might not work in a terminal: it should work in GUI Emacs. You can always bind a different key to the function though: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c e") #'org-insert-structure-template)`. This is just an example: choose a key that is not used already.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a function which inserts the code block:

```lisp
(defun org-insert-source-block (name language switches header)
  "Asks name, language, switches, header.
Inserts org-mode source code snippet"
  (interactive "sname? 
slanguage? 
sswitches? 
sheader? ")
  (insert 
   (if (string= name "")
       ""
     (concat "#+NAME: " name) )
   (format "
#+BEGIN_SRC %s %s %s

#+END_SRC" language switches header
)
   )
  (forward-line -1)
  (goto-char (line-end-position))
  )
```

Comment: Because it’s better to have an org function to call than to copy-paste stuff from SE (people could write it themselves, but that’s probably what would happen).

Answer (score 7):

On my box 99% of the time I'm creating source blocks and 1% of the time I'm doing everything else. For the 1% Easy Templates are perfect and for the 99% I've got a YaSnippet.

- It creates a unique `NAME` using `org-id` but that doesn't matter just us anything) and then it asks me what language I want to use limiting it those the ones that I told Org-Mode Literate Programming (babel)
- Presents a list of language types that you told Org-Mode that you want to use, and to choose from, instead of typing every type (though I don't use all of them)
- If the language has to generates a file it asks for the output file name

Here is the YaSnippet with my supporting code at the end.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# key: sc
# name: Source Block
# group: HELP
# contributor: gcr@wisdomandwonder.com
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
# --
#+NAME: ${1:`(help/org-id-new)`}
#+BEGIN_SRC ${2:$$(let ((langs (sort (-map (lambda (x) (symbol-name (car x))) (if (-contains? org-babel-load-languages '(js . t)) (-snoc org-babel-load-languages '(javascript . t)) org-babel-do-load-languages)) 'string<))) (yas-choose-value (if (-contains? langs "shell") (-snoc langs "sh") langs)))}${2:$(when (-contains? '("ditaa" "dot" "plantuml") yas-text) (concat " :file \\"./image/" (yas-field-value 1) ".png\\""))} $3
$0
#+END_SRC
```

It requires dash and org-mode loaded.

```
(require 'org-id)
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'nil)
(setq org-id-prefix (concat "org_" (user-real-login-name) "_" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") "_" (system-name)))
(setq org-id-method 'uuid)
(defun help/org-id-new ()
  "Re-purposing `org-id' hit a snag when colons were forbidden in Source-Block
  names. Adding support for a user-defined Org-Id separator would have fixed
  this but with no benefit to Org-Id. So this function removes the colon
  instead.
 "
  (interactive)
  (let* ((gend (org-id-new))
         (newid (replace-regexp-in-string ":" "_" gend)))
    newid))
```

Here is an example of you might this id function:

```
C-u M-:
(insert (help/org-id-new))
```

Results in

```
org_gcr_2017-08-06_mara_DD608C9A-33B0-4A8D-9123-298746BE973Anil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;;; package --- Summary
;;; Commentary:
;;; Code:
(defvar org-sai-src-default "C++"
 "This is the list used to store the default label for source code section.")

(defun org-insert-src-block ()
  "Insert the source code section in `org-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((src-code-types
          '("emacs-lisp" "python" "C" "sh" "java" "js" "clojure" "C++" "css"
            "calc" "asymptote" "dot" "gnuplot" "ledger" "lilypond" "mscgen"
            "octave" "oz" "plantuml" "R" "sass" "screen" "sql" "awk" "ditaa"
            "haskell" "latex" "lisp" "matlab" "ocaml" "org" "perl" "ruby"
            "scheme" "sqlite"))
         (src-prompt-str
          (concat "Source code type (default "
                  org-sai-src-default
                  "): "))
         (temp-src-code-types 
          (cons org-sai-src-default src-code-types))
         (src-type-str
          (completing-read src-prompt-str temp-src-code-types
                           nil nil nil nil org-sai-src-default)))
    (setq org-sai-src-default src-type-str))
    (insert (format "#+BEGIN_SRC %s\n" src-type-str))
    (newline)
    (org-indent-line)
    (insert "#+END_SRC\n")
    (forward-line -2))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; keybinding for inserting code blocks
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'org-insert-src-block)))

(provide 'orgAuxiliary)
;;; orgAuxiliary.el ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting @mgalgs comment from above as this is the correct answer now:

[Quickly insert source blocks in org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12841/quickly-insert-source-blocks-in-org-mode#comment98767_12847)

> Nowadays it's C-c C-, which runs (org-insert-structure-template) –
> mgalgs
> Jan 8, 2021 at 19:24

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interactive function I came up with that not only adds a source code block, but if you are using [Org Babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html) You can also pull in the contents of an existing file with the `:tangle` header argument conveniently added for you.

I have this setup with the following key binding

```lisp
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c s") 'org-insert-source-code-block)
```

So to just insert a plain source block with a prompt for the language just run `C-c s` and if you want to also be prompted for a file to 'tangle' with `C-u C-c s`

It is pretty cool to 'suck-in' the contents of a file, edit it right there in org mode then '[tangle](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html)' your changes to update the original file.

And the function itself:

```lisp
(defun org-insert-source-code-block(&optional language file)
  "Insert source code block for LANGUAGE.  Optionally pull in FILE contents.
Will prompt for LANGUAGE when called interactively.
With a `\\[universal-argument]' prefix, prompts for FILE.
The `:tangle FILE` header argument will be added when pulling in file contents."
  (interactive)
  (let ((col (current-column))
        (lang (or language (read-from-minibuffer "Source block language: ") ))
        (file (if current-prefix-arg (read-file-name "Enter file name: ") nil)))
    (insert
     (format "#+begin_src %s%s" lang (if file (concat " :tangle " file) "")))
    (newline)(newline)
    (move-to-column col t)(insert "#+end_src")(newline)
    (forward-line -2)(move-to-column col t)
    (if file (insert-file-contents file))))
```