# Is it a default keybinding to insert #+BEGIN_SRC [...] #+END_SRC?

Tags: org-babel

I've searched the manual and I didn't find anything useful. It's annoying to write every time the tags to surround the code, and I'm surprised that org doesn't provide a macro to avoid a so boring task.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12841/15748).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for "`<s`" and hitting `[Tab]`.

These are called "Easy Templates", and the syntax is a `<` followed by the template selector.
`[Tab]` expands them.

[Here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates) is a list of other templates you can quickly insert like this.

**2019 update:** "Easy Templates" are now "Structure Templates", and expansion with `<` is no longer default behavior, though you can turn it can turn it on by running `M-x customize-variable` on `org-modules` and enabling `org-tempo`, or you can use the new default keybinding which is bound to `C-c C-,`.

Comment: Seems like "Easy Templates" are now "Structure Templates", and a corrected manual link for that is: https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html#Structure-Templates