# Emacs org-mode error in tempo tags

Tags: org-mode

I'm using emacs with org mode tempo tags,
based on this questions and answers

[Q and A 1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46795/is-it-possible-to-add-templates-other-than-begin-end-to-org-structure-temp)
[Q and A 2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40571/how-to-set-a-short-cut-for-begin-src-end-src/40587#40587)

[image]I get the feeling that I need to require org-tempo, but I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp ("#+BEGIN_NOTES\n?\n#+END_NOTES"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I'm using ox-reveal, and add an item to the org-mode-template-alist which is the notes one. this should be fix an use the new model. there is also a pull requests in the ox-reveal but it seems not maintained or going too slow in development.

[Several pull requests for solving this issue](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/pulls)